# Getting 'Must declare the scalar variable' errors when running stored proc

Tags: sql-server-2008

```
USE db_preprac_v1_2
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE sp_accessory
@repID AS SMALLINT
AS
```

--Create a temp copy of table

```
    SELECT * 
    INTO #tempAcc
    FROM accessory 
    GO
```

--Add a column called Printed

```
    ALTER TABLE #tempAcc
    ADD
    Printed SMALLINT
    GO
```

--Set all the values in that column equal to 0

```
    UPDATE #tempAcc
    SET Printed = 0
    GO


    --Declare variables

    DECLARE @RepName AS VARCHAR(30)
    DECLARE @RepTel AS VARCHAR(10)
    DECLARE @AccID AS SMALLINT
    DECLARE @AccDesc AS VARCHAR(30)
    DECLARE @AccPrice AS MONEY
    DECLARE @Quantity AS SMALLINT
    DECLARE @total AS MONEY = 0
    --DECLARE @ID AS SMALLINT = @repID
```

/*
    Checks if representative id is valid and if valid, it displays all the accessories
    that the representative sold. If not valid, it prints a error message.
    */

```
IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT rep_id FROM representative WHERE rep_id = @repID)
>BEGIN
    PRINT 'Invalid representative id'
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    SELECT @RepName = representative.rep_name, @RepTel = representative.rep_tel
    FROM representative
    WHERE @repID = representative.rep_id

    PRINT '************************'
    PRINT 'Accessory Details Report'
    PRINT '************************'
    PRINT ''
    PRINT 'Representative Information'
    PRINT ''
    PRINT 'Reps Name: ' + @RepName
    PRINT 'Reps Telephone: ' + @RepTel
    PRINT ''

    PRINT 'Accessories Sold by this Representative'
```

--Creates a while loop to iterate through the rows

```
WHILE EXISTS (SELECT *
  FROM #tempAcc
  WHERE Printed = 0) 

  BEGIN 
    SELECT @AccID = MIN (acc_id)
    FROM #tempAcc
    WHERE Printed = 0

    SELECT @AccDesc = accessory.acc_desc, @AccPrice = accessory.acc_price, @Quantity = accessory_detail.quantity
    FROM accessory
    JOIN accessory_detail
    ON accessory.acc_id = accessory_detail.acc
    JOIN representative
    ON accessory_detail.rep = representative.rep_id
    WHERE @repID = representative.rep_id

    PRINT 'Accessory Desc: ' + @AccDesc
    PRINT 'Accessory Price: ' + CAST(@AccPrice AS VARCHAR)
    PRINT 'Quantity in Car: ' + CAST(@Quantity AS VARCHAR)
    PRINT ''

    UPDATE #tempAcc
       SET Printed = 1
       WHERE @AccID = acc_id
```

--Calculates the total value of accesories sold

```
    SELECT @total = @total + @AccPrice
  END
END

    PRINT 'The total value of the accessories sold is: ' + CAST(@total AS VARCHAR)
    PRINT 'Transaction Date: ' + CAST(GETDATE() AS VARCHAR)     

GO
```

--to execute the procedure, supply an input value of the representative id.

```
EXEC sp_accessory 3
GO

DROP PROCEDURE sp_accessory
GO
```

This is what i get when i execute the code using Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio:

```
Msg 137, Level 15, State 2, Line 15
Must declare the scalar variable "@repID".
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 19
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'ELSE'.
Msg 137, Level 15, State 2, Line 23
Must declare the scalar variable "@repID".
Msg 137, Level 15, State 2, Line 53
Must declare the scalar variable "@repID".

--------------------------------------------------------------------------**
```

Comment: After fixing the errors I noted below, I'm now getting it to successfully print out what I expected. Are you still having problems?

Answer (score 2):

1) Don't name any procedure "sp_(ANYTHING)"; "sp_" should be used for system stored procedures.

2) You have three `GO` statements in the middle of your procedure. If you run this as a `CREATE` script, it's going to assume that the first `GO` marks the end of the script.

3) You have a stray > before your `BEGIN` after your `IF`.

4) Why are you dropping the procedure after you execute it?

5) You're not multiplying the Quantity by the price to get the per-line subtotal. The total is therefore incorrect. Change this:

`SELECT @total = @total + @AccPrice`

to this:

`SELECT @total = @total + (@Quantity * @AccPrice)`

Comment: SELECT *, 0 as Printed INTO #tempAcc FROM accessory this will also shorten the process.

Comment: @Adam V thanks a lot, i have no errors anymore all thanks to you. I am dropping the procedure because when executed i keep seeing the message that it already exists

Comment: @Adam, the code runs perfectly but it doesn't print the desired results.

Comment: @user1250715, what does it print? Nothing? No lines that contain variables? Empty data in place of variables?

Comment: @Adam, it prints the same data(accessory) that the representative has sold instead of only those accessories sold by the representative.

Comment: How can i use the while loop to print only the accessories sold by the representative? Because at the moment it prints everything in the temp table even those which the representative didn't sell.